# Android NETWORK location is not responding

Tags: android, networking, location

I'm initiating the location provider this way:

```
    LocationManager     locationManager     = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Intent              locationIntent      = new Intent(context, LocationReceiver.class);        
    PendingIntent       pendingIntent       = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, locationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                                                MINIMAL_TIME,
                                                MINIMAL_DISTANCE,
                                                pendingIntent);
```

Then, my receiver is implemented this way:

```
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    if(intent.hasExtra(LocationManager.KEY_LOCATION_CHANGED)) {
        Location location = (Location)intent.getExtras().get(LocationManager.KEY_LOCATION_CHANGED);
```

My issue is the following:

On Galaxy Nexus, the receiver is never triggered.

I succeed to make it triggered if I manually started the Google Maps application before. Then, it works without any issue. If I reset the phone (remove the battery), then the issue appears again.

Any solution for this?

I went through a lot of similar issues on stackoverflow, but never found a working solution.

EDIT:

I found that this issue is happening using a SIM with no data access, even if WiFi is enebaled and connected. Using a SIM with data access, this issue is not happening.

On a Nexus One, this issue is not happening, whatever the SIM I use (with data or without data).

Comment: Have you set required permissions in manifest file?

Comment: Yes. I have these permissions: INTERNET, ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE, ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS, ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION.

Anyway, it wouldn't succeed after going to Google Maps if manifest were bad.